# VueJS not building due to Android Javascript webView callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kotlin

I would like to have a WebView page callback to my Android app. I have successfully done this using vanilla HTML page. When I add the same JavaScript code to my VueJS app, it does not want to build, and gives me an `ELIFECYCLE` error.

In my Kotlin code, I have the following:

```
binding.webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(), "Android")

private inner class JavaScriptInterface {
  fun showWallet(string: String) {
    AppPreference.PREFERENCE_SCREEN_TYPE = Constants.SCREEN_USER_DASHBOARD
    mainActivity.getNavController().navigate(R.id.action_placeOrder_to_userDashboardFragment)
   }
}
```

`Android` is my JavaScript object I've declared, and the function is `showWallet`, which navigates the user to another fragment.

In my VueJS code, I have the following:

```
let devicedUsed = this.$store.state.devicedUsed;
if (devicedUsed === 'apple'){
  window.webkit.messageHandlers.message.postMessage('backToWallet');
}else{ //is Android device
  Android.showWallet('backToWallet');
}
```

The above callback works without any issues in vanilla HTML. My problem is the above code does not build, and I get an error that `Android` is not defined. It seems VueJS is looking for `Android`, which is only defined in the Kotlin code.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `window.` prefix to tell the compiler that it's a global variable:

```js
// BEFORE:
Android.showWallet('backToWallet')

// AFTER:
window.Android.showWallet('backToWallet')
```